# Crear paginador para un API externo en PHP

Tags: php, api

Estoy importando un JSON de todas las cervezas de una API de [**Brewerydb**](https://www.brewerydb.com/).

En la API las cervezas salen de 50 en 50 y tiene 23 páginas. Necesito crear un paginador para que cuando le dé a siguiente, pase por `GET` una variable llamada `pag` y se incremente la variable de página dentro de la variable `$uri` y vaya avanzando de página o cuando le dé a anterior vaya hacia atrás.

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
<?php 

    $aux = 0;
    if (isset($_GET['pag'])) {
        $_GET['pag']+=$aux;
        echo $_GET['pag']."<br>";
    }else{
        $_GET['pag'] = 1;
    }
     $uri = 'https://sandbox-api.brewerydb.com/v2/beers?p='.$_GET['pag'].'&key=a1dc1446191ebea66072bac6e03a13f6';
    $reqPrefs['http']['method'] = 'GET';
    $reqPrefs['http']['header'] = 'X-Auth-Token: 7c112489898843e6b4949f49284587ed';
    $stream_context = stream_context_create($reqPrefs);
    $response = file_get_contents($uri, false, $stream_context);
    $cervezas = json_decode($response);

 ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Birras del mundo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

 </head>
 <body>
    <h1>Cervezas del mundo</h1>
    <ul>
        <?php 
            foreach ($cervezas->data as $cerveza) {
                print "<li><a href='verbirra.php'>".$cerveza->nameDisplay."</a></li>";
            }
         ?>
    </ul>



            <a href="birrasdelmundo.php?pag=1">Anterior</a>
            <a href="birrasdelmundo.php?pag=1">Siguiente</a>


    <!-- Scripts Boostrap -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

principalmente, si la cantidad de paginas es automática, deberás solicitar a dicha api la cantidad de paginas exactas, ahora si solo son 23 paginas y sabes que no habrá mas ni menos, exactamente 23, solo debes jugar un poco con las variables

```
$pagact= $_GET['pag'];
$pagtotal=23;
$pagant=1;
$pagdes=2;

if(!empty($pagact)){
    if($pagact>=1 && $pagact<=$pagtotal){
        if($pagact==1){
            $pagant=1;
            $pagdes=2;
        }else if($pagact==$pagtotal){
            $pagant=($pagtotal-1);
            $pagdes=$pagtotal;
        }else if($pagact>1 && $pagact>$pagtotal){
            $pagant= ($pagact-1);
            $pagdes= ($pagact+1);
        }
    }
}

<a href="birrasdelmundo.php?pag=<?=$pagant?>">Anterior</a>
<a href="birrasdelmundo.php?pag=<?=$pagdes?>">Siguiente</a>
```

como ves el método es sencillo, tienes la pagina actual, paginas total, pagina anterior y pagina siguiente, primero verificas que el GET no este vació, una vez que tenemos la pagina actual, verificamos que la misma se encuentre en una numeración entre la pagina 1 y 23, una vez echo esto, ya podemos empezar a separar las diferencias, si la pagina actual es la primera, las direcciones seran 1 y 2, luego, si la pagina actual es la ultima dará 22 y 23, ahora si la pagina actual esta entre 2 y 22, simplemente sumara y restara un numero en dicha pagina.

Comment: No me funciona... avanza a la pagina 2 y luego ya no avanza mas. Por cierto en el enlace dentro de la variable pag no habria que poner <?php echo $pagant ?> ?

Comment: por favor, revisa el código antes de pedir ayuda, así no aprendes nada, todo se aprende con prueba y error, no esperes que te pasen el codigo ya listo, reemplaza "$pagdesp" por "$pagdes" en la variable que tiene el botón siguiente

Answer (score 0):

He dividido la respuesta en varias partes para facilitar su lectura y comprensión.

### Lógica inicial

Usaremos el valor de la página enviado por `GET` sólo si se envió, convirtiendo previamente su contenido a entero y, en caso contrario, asignaremos como página actual la `1`:

```
/* Si hemos recibido el número de página por GET lo usamos */
if (empty($_GET['pag']) === false) {
    $pagina_actual = intval($_GET['pag']);
} else {
    $pagina_actual = 1;
}
```

### Página actual

Usamos como página actual la que nos entrega el API (`$cervezas->currentPage`) y no la que contiene la variable `$pagina_actual`. De este modo si usamos un número de página inválido (mayor al número de páginas o `0`) se usará el que el API nos ha indicado que es el que vamos a mostrar.

```
<button class="btn btn-success" disabled>
  <?= htmlspecialchars($cervezas->currentPage) ?>
</button>
```

Fíjate en el uso de [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://php.net/es/htmlspecialchars) para enviar al navegador **cualquier texto**, para escapar los caracteres HTML que pueda contener y, también, evitar problemas de seguridad por [XSS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

### Página anterior

El botón de página anterior se mostrará normal a partir de la página 2 (`$cervezas->currentPage > 1`), enviando por `GET` la página anterior (`$cervezas->currentPage - 1`):

```
<?php if ($cervezas->currentPage > 1): ?>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?= htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>?pag=<?= htmlspecialchars($cervezas->currentPage - 1) ?>">Anterior</a>
<?php else: ?>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" disabled>Anterior</button>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Si estamos en la primera página se mostrará un botón desactivado (que no se puede pulsar).

### Página siguiente

El botón de página siguiente se mostrará normal si no hemos llegado a la última página (`$cervezas->currentPage < $cervezas->numberOfPages`), enviando por `GET` la página siguiente (`$cervezas->currentPage + 1`):

```
<?php if ($cervezas->currentPage < $cervezas->numberOfPages): ?>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?= htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>?pag=<?= htmlspecialchars($cervezas->currentPage + 1) ?>">Siguiente</a>
<?php else: ?>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" disabled>Siguiente</button>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Si estamos en la última página (o posterior si lo intentamos manualmente) se mostrará, igual que antes, un botón desactivado (que no se puede pulsar).

---

He creado un repositorio github con el código necesario para ver todas estas sugerencias aplicadas (https://github.com/ojgarciab/231021-stackoverflow-es) y un enlace a gitpod para que puedas probarlo en línea:

[image: Gitpod Ready-to-Code]